# Prestashop encrypt plain text password

Tags: php, web-services, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

From the plain text password what are steps to do before to add it inside the database.

Because of the blank schema ask for passwd (=hash) and secure_key, how I can get this information with php and Prestashop API ?

I'm using Prestashop 1.7.1

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

For PHP use [php Password Hashing Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php) `password_hash` and `password_verify`.

Comment: Thanks this is helpful.